# Как правильно и красиво переписать этот код

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, инспекция-кода

Создаю приложение pyqt5. Есть такой кусок кода, который записывает состояние чекбоксов во флаги и в соответствии с этими состояниями добавляет в текстовую переменную названия выбранных этапов. Этот код работает, но хотелось бы привести его к нормальному виду(изменение индексов в цикле, например). Как это можно сделать?

```
self.flag_stage1 = self.check_stage1.isChecked()
self.flag_stage2 = self.check_stage2.isChecked()
self.flag_stage3 = self.check_stage3.isChecked()
self.text_stage = ""
if self.flag_stage1 is True:
    self.text_stage = self.text_stage + "   Этап 1\n"
if self.flag_stage2 is True:
    self.text_stage = self.text_stage + "   Этап 2\n"
if self.flag_stage3 is True:
    self.text_stage = self.text_stage + "   Этап 3\n"
if (self.flag_stage1 or self.flag_stage2 or self.flag_stage3) is False:
    self.text_stage = "Ни один этап не выбран\n"
self.logBrowser.append(log("Испытание запущено\n"
                           "Выбранные этапы:\n" + self.text_stage))
```

Comment: Чтобы в цикле обрабатывать, нужно чтобы у вас были списки flag_stage и check_stage, а не отдельные поля. Чтобы написать конкретный код, нужно видеть как у вас поля check_stage1 - 3 инициализируются. Последнее условие лучше записать не через `is False`, а через отрицание: `not (self.flag_stage1 or self.flag_stage2 or self.flag_stage3)` (сейчас если не вникать код, можно подумать, что вы хотели написать проверку, что хотя бы одно из полей равно False, но это не так).

Comment: Поля check_stage1 - 3 инициализируются в файле дизайна, который, в свою очередь, я получаю из Qt Designer. 
По поводу **is False** согласен, ваш вариант логичнее

Comment: Я бы и `is True` убрал, лишняя проверка, достаточно сами переменные проверять: `if self.flag_stage1:`. Еще можно упросить сложение через `+=` -> `self.text_stage += "   Этап 1\n"` А у чекбоксов, случаем тексты не `Этап 1/2/3`? Тогда можно в переменную `self.text_stage` засовывать текст чекбоксов, а сами чекбоксы куда-нибудь положить, например, в список и перебирать в цикле

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно переписать примерно так (от промежуточных `flag_stage` вообще решил избавиться, просто проходим циклом по чекбоксам):

```
check_stages = [self.check_stage1, self.check_stage2, self.check_stage3]

text_stages = ""
for i, check_stage in enumerate(check_stages, start=1):
    if check_stage.isChecked():
        text_stages += f"   Этап {i}\n"

if not text_stages:  # Текст пустой, значит ничего не было выбрано
    text_stages = "Ни один этап не выбран\n"

self.logBrowser.append(log("Испытание запущено\n"
                           "Выбранные этапы:\n" + text_stages))
```

Еще вариант, не собираем строку `text_stages`, а формируем список этапов, и только в конце объединяем в общую строку:

```
stages = [f"   Этап {i}" for i, check_stage in enumerate(check_stages, start=1)
          if check_stage.isChecked()]

if not stages:  # Список пустой, значит ничего не было выбрано
    text_stages = "Ни один этап не выбран\n"
else:
    text_stages = "\n".join(stages)
```

Comment: Вместо последнего `if` можно применить тернарный оператор. Читабельность почти не пострадает, а строки сэкономятся )  Хотя дело вкуса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На самом деле переменные flag_stage нужны для других нужд.

Comment: @Александр для flag_stage можно отдельно получить список, например с помощью `flag_stages = [check_stage.isChecked() for check_stage in check_stages]`